# Why Error code 253 when I build my cordova application

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, build

For a while I can not compile my application correctly.
My application uses cordova and Angular 1, I tried with several versions of ipad tablet without success.

I reinstalled the application and updated all the plugins cordova, without success I upgraded cordova, gulp, iOS on my tablet, ionnic, without success too..

**Latest configuration :**
 - ipad 4 Version 10.3.3 
 - cordova : 7.0.1 
 - ionic : 2.2.3
 - AngularJS 1.X

**Plugins List :**
cordova-custom-config 3.1.4 "cordova-custom-config"
cordova-plugin-client-certificate-addictic 0.0.1 "Client Certificate"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.1.5 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.4 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

**Compilation with Console :** 
‘cordova run iOS —device’

Error in Console bash :

> Starting debug of iPad 4 'iPad 4'
>   (2399acc62866ac2ac6000ad55f470e9e43d69dab) connected through USB...
>   2017-09-05 09:20:09.735 ios-deploy[9492:9633908] [ !! ] Unable to
>   locate DeviceSupport directory. This probably means you don't have
>   Xcode installed, you will need to launch the app manually and logging
>   output will not be shown! Error: Error code 253 for command:
>   ios-deploy with args:
>   --justlaunch,--no-wifi,-d,-b,/Users/agenceaddictic/Apps/crpvapp/platforms/ios/build/device/VigiMedic.app

**With Xcode 8.3.3 :**

iOS Deployment Target : 10.3 (is the same error with 9.x)
Device iPad 4
Use Release for command-line builds
Default compiler : Apple LLVM 8,1

I launch :  « Build and then run the current scheme »
Application Builded but don’t correct running

[view screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLK65.png)

Comment: check out this link - https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy/issues/292

Comment: Think you, building is fine now with Xcode and Bash. But my application in IOS don't work.

Comment: update the additional info in the question not as answer